# <jsp:include> unpredictable behavior

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Following code present in nav.jsp

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="lt_previous">Previous </span></a>
</li>
<li><span class="dividerIcon floatLeft"></span></li>   
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="lt_next">Next </span></a>
</li>   
</ul>
```

When I'm including nav.jsp page in main.jsp page using `<jsp:include>` directive I'm expecting output as
Previous | Next

But its giving me exact inverted result like
Next | Previous

Why is it so?

Comment: what is the css on those pages where you want to include this snippet?

Comment: I always thought ul means "unordered list" ? @Java1

Comment: @donfuxx - you are right.  mine was a stupid comment anyway and has been rightfully deleted, hopefully never to raise it's head in shame again.

Comment: Hey folks thanks for reverting back and I appreciate your help.
@donfuxx You are right! it was a CSS issue and HTML source were generated correctly. 
Lesson to learn : First check the generated HTML source for cases like including JSP pages.